# Postgres Materialized View Auto Refresh

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views, postgresql-13

Is there any way to write a materialized view in PostgreSQL which refreshes it self automatically by specifying something while creating it?

Comment: No, that's currently not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, it's not available, you can use the following command to refresh it whenever you make changes to the base tables:
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW MY_NAME